# wrong time at Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: linux, vmware, ntp, clock

I have VM with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, and time is wrong. The difference is about 15 hours. I synchronize it via `sudo ntpdate 1.ro.pool.ntp.org`every day and then it becomes right, but next day I have this problem again.

Comment: This situation is particularly well known by people using VmWare....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VM is following the virtualization host time that is wrong. Whist you are able to set it up, to the current time, with occasional `ntpdate` commands, it will diverge rather quickly to the host time again, as you are witnessing.

To fix the time, you can either:

1. fix the host/hypervisor time and setup NTP properly on the hypervisor (it is recommended to do it nonetheless to keep all the infra-structure/logs on the same time);
2. tell the VM to not follow the host time without running a time synchronization daemon (nonetheless there is the phenomenon of time compression, and time will slowly diverge from the official time after the `ntpdate`);
3. tell the VM to not follow the host time **and** run an NTP synchronization daemon

Option 2 is not a desired setup, but I included it to illustrate a point. I have followed option 1 once in a while with *very light VM setups*,  *however* Option 3 is the course of action recommended by VMWare white papers.

Assuming a  VMware host, For disabling the syncronization with the vmware host, you have to have (open) vmtools installed, and run upon boot, as root or with sudo:

```
vmware-toolbox-cmd timesync disable
```

And then to install a NTP daemon, you can either install `ntpd`, or the `chrony` daemon.

Nevertheless, I would also stress again, that from an operational point of view, it is also advisable that the virtualization host machine has the time/NTP configuration fixed.

See also this post from our sister site ServerFault [Do I need to run a NTP server in every VM?](https://serverfault.com/questions/488355/do-i-need-to-run-a-ntp-server-in-every-vm/488528)

> It should be noted that time not only "can" drift away, but will drift
>   away due to the fact that intervals between timer interrupts (which
>   timekeeping on OS is often based on) are stretched and compressed as
>   the hypervisor would see fit.