# Should I disable systemd-timesyncd if ntp is installed?

Tags: ntp, ntpd, systemd-timesyncd

Is there any issue with running `systemd-timesyncd` and `ntp` on the same machine?

I'm asking this because I have started using `NTP` on all servers but the `systemd-timesyncd` is running there as well. Should I disable it? Any issues with both running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running both at the same time is not recommended. Both services might be using difference ntp servers with slight difference in time. So your server will experience time corrections very frequently: time synced by ntp service will get changed by systemd-timesyncd, and vice-verse.

You may already know, you can disable `systemd-timesyncd` start on boot and also stop the running service simultaneously using:

```
systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd --now
```

Comment: timesyncd is not exactly full NTP...see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/504381/chrony-vs-systemd-timesyncd-what-are-the-differences-and-use-cases-as-ntp-cli/504387#504387

Comment: It isn't even close to be a proper `ntp` client.  It is strip implementation features without any gain, actually.  Just a `NIH` from `systemd` group.

Answer (score 1):

You can also fully disable `systemd-timesyncd` using:

```
timedatectl set-ntp 0
```

Or enable using:

```
timedatectl set-ntp 1
```

See:

```
timedatectl --help
```

To check if `systemd-timesyncd` is enabled or disabled simply type `timedatectl status` and check the value of "***Network time on:***" where "***yes***" indicates **enabled** and "***no***" means **disabled**.

Sorry for the separate answer but I can't add a comment due to lack of reputation.

Comment: This messes with chrony, if I have chrony installed. I don't think it's the right way to disable it.